# Copy column cells from active row to new row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add a row below the active cell and then copy the cells from columns E-J in the active row to the newly inserted row.

```vb
Sub Addrow()
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    
    Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "E"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "F"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "G"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "H"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "I"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "J")).Select
    
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1), "E")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        
End Sub
```

I believe the problem is selecting the cells range after the new row has been inserted.

Comment: after the insert remove all other lines and replace them with this one line: `Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "E"), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "J")).Copy Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1).Row, "E")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the problems might be that you can't provide more than 2 arguments to the `Range` function.

Also, you generally want to avoid relying on a sheet or range to be active whilst the code is running (because the `ActiveSheet` or `ActiveCell` may change, which may make your code behave unpredictably/unreliably).

`Intersect` is a function that will return the range shared by all of its arguments. In this case, it returns cells which are common to the range `columns E to J` and the range `row of the Active cell`.

`Range.Copy` accepts a `Destination` argument, so you can pass the destination range to it directly.

```
Sub AddRow()

    Dim selectedCell As Range
    Set selectedCell = ActiveCell

    Dim parentSheet As Worksheet
    Set parentSheet = selectedCell.Parent

    selectedCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown

    With Intersect(parentSheet.Range("E:J"), selectedCell.EntireRow)
        .Copy .Offset(1)
    End With

End Sub
```

I did test the code and it seemed to do what you described (i.e. copy from the selected row and paste to the newly inserted row below it).